# Add class name to all instances of a particular class

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have 3 sections which share the same code.

When I select a currency in Section 1, I want the same currency to be selected in section 2 and 3 as well. Also, when I expand the currency list by clicking the 'Show more' link in one section, I want the list to be expanded in every section. I've tried the below, but it is only affecting one section and the show more link seems to not work all the time. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  var $ = jQuery;

  $('.currency-btn').off('click').on('click', function(event) {
    if (event) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
    var currency = this.id ? this.id.split('-')[0] : null;
    var $btn = $(this);
    if (currency && $('.' + currency + '-btn').length) {

      $('.currencies').hide();
      $('.currency-' + currency).show();

      $('.currency-btn').removeClass('active');
      $btn.addClass('active');

      $btn.show().prev('span').show();
      $('a.currency-more').off('click').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).prev('span').remove().end().remove();
        $('a.currency-btn').show().prev('span').show();
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.active { color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sec1">
  <div class="currency-btn-section">
    <h4>Section 1</h4>
    <b>CURRENCY:</b>
    <a href="#" id="" class="usd-btn currency-btn active">US$</a>
    <span>|</span> <a href="#" id="" class="gbp-btn currency-btn">GBP£</a>
    <span>|</span> <a href="#" id="" class="eur-btn currency-btn">EUR€</a>
    <span style="display:none">|</span> <a style="display:none" href="#" id="" class="aud-btn currency-btn">AUS$</a>
    <span style="display:none">|</span> <a style="display:none" href="#" id="" class="cad-btn currency-btn">CAN$</a>
    <span style="display:none">|</span> <a style="display:none" href="#" id="" class="mxn-btn currency-btn">MEX$</a>
    <span style="display:none">|</span> <a style="display:none" href="#" id="" class="sgd-btn currency-btn">SGP$</a>
    <span class='currency-more'>|</span>
    <a href="#" class="currency-more">Show more&hellip;</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="sec2">
  <h4>Section 2</h4>
  <b>CURRENCY:</b>
  <a href="#" id="" class="usd-btn currency-btn active">US$</a>
  <span>|</span> <a href="#" id="" class="gbp-btn currency-btn">GBP£</a>
  <span>|</span> <a href="#" id="" class="eur-btn currency-btn">EUR€</a>
  <span style="display:none">|</span> <a style="display:none" href="#" id="" class="aud-btn currency-btn">AUS$</a>
  <span style="display:none">|</span> <a style="display:none" href="#" id="" class="cad-btn currency-btn">CAN$</a>
  <span style="display:none">|</span> <a style="display:none" href="#" id="" class="mxn-btn currency-btn">MEX$</a>
  <span style="display:none">|</span> <a style="display:none" href="#" id="" class="sgd-btn currency-btn">SGP$</a>
  <span class='currency-more'>|</span>
  <a href="#" class="currency-more">Show more&hellip;</a>
</div>
</div>
<div class="sec3">
  <h4>Section 3</h4>
  <b>CURRENCY:</b>
  <a href="#" id="" class="usd-btn currency-btn active">US$</a>
  <span>|</span> <a href="#" id="" class="gbp-btn currency-btn">GBP£</a>
  <span>|</span> <a href="#" id="" class="eur-btn currency-btn">EUR€</a>
  <span style="display:none">|</span> <a style="display:none" href="#" id="" class="aud-btn currency-btn">AUS$</a>
  <span style="display:none">|</span> <a style="display:none" href="#" id="" class="cad-btn currency-btn">CAN$</a>
  <span style="display:none">|</span> <a style="display:none" href="#" id="" class="mxn-btn currency-btn">MEX$</a>
  <span style="display:none">|</span> <a style="display:none" href="#" id="" class="sgd-btn currency-btn">SGP$</a>
  <span class='currency-more'>|</span>
  <a href="#" class="currency-more">Show more&hellip;</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Check this edits, Your main error that you are not using each while you are selecting many elements. and you just need to be more simple while passing data through elements attributes, like adding `currency` attribute to the buttons.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.currency-btn').each((index, el) => {

        $(el).off('click').on('click', function (event) {
   
            if (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
            }
    
            var $btn = $(this);
            var currency = $btn.attr('currency');

            if (currency && $('.' + currency + '-btn').length) {

                $('.currency-btn').removeClass('active');
                var sameButtons = $(`[currency="${currency}"]`)
                sameButtons.each((i, bttn)=>{
                    $(bttn).addClass('active')
                })

        
            }
        })

    });


    $('a.currency-more').each((i, btn)=>{
        $(btn).off('click').on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            $('a.currency-more').css('display', 'none');
            $('.currency-btn').css('display', 'inline-block');
        });
    }) 
});
```

```css
.active { color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sec1">
    <div class="currency-btn-section">
        <h4>Section 1</h4>
        <b>CURRENCY:</b>
        <a href="#" id="" currency="usd" class="usd-btn currency-btn active">US$</a>
        <span>|</span> <a href="#" currency="gbp" id="" class="gbp-btn currency-btn">GBP£</a>
        <span>|</span> <a href="#" currency="eur" id="" class="eur-btn currency-btn">EUR€</a>
        <span style="display:none">|</span> <a style="display:none" href="#" currency="aud" id=""
            class="aud-btn currency-btn">AUS$</a>
        <span style="display:none">|</span> <a style="display:none" href="#" currency="cad" id=""
            class="cad-btn currency-btn">CAN$</a>
        <span style="display:none">|</span> <a style="display:none" href="#" currency="mxn" id=""
            class="mxn-btn currency-btn">MEX$</a>
        <span style="display:none">|</span> <a style="display:none" href="#" currency="sgd" id=""
            class="sgd-btn currency-btn">SGP$</a>
        <span class='currency-more'>|</span>
        <a href="#" class="currency-more">Show more&hellip;</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="sec2">
    <h4>Section 2</h4>
    <b>CURRENCY:</b>
    <a href="#" id="" currency="usd" class="usd-btn currency-btn active">US$</a>
    <span>|</span> <a href="#" currency="gbp" id="" class="gbp-btn currency-btn">GBP£</a>
    <span>|</span> <a href="#" currency="eur" id="" class="eur-btn currency-btn">EUR€</a>
    <span style="display:none">|</span> <a style="display:none" href="#" currency="aud" id=""
        class="aud-btn currency-btn">AUS$</a>
    <span style="display:none">|</span> <a style="display:none" href="#" currency="cad" id=""
        class="cad-btn currency-btn">CAN$</a>
    <span style="display:none">|</span> <a style="display:none" href="#" currency="mxn" id=""
        class="mxn-btn currency-btn">MEX$</a>
    <span style="display:none">|</span> <a style="display:none" href="#" currency="sgd" id=""
        class="sgd-btn currency-btn">SGP$</a>
    <span class='currency-more'>|</span>
    <a href="#" class="currency-more">Show more&hellip;</a>
</div>
</div>
<div class="sec3">
    <h4>Section 3</h4>
    <b>CURRENCY:</b>
    <a href="#" id="" currency="usd" class="usd-btn currency-btn active">US$</a>
    <span>|</span> <a href="#" currency="gbp" id="" class="gbp-btn currency-btn">GBP£</a>
    <span>|</span> <a href="#" currency="eur" id="" class="eur-btn currency-btn">EUR€</a>
    <span style="display:none">|</span> <a style="display:none" href="#" currency="aud" id=""
        class="aud-btn currency-btn">AUS$</a>
    <span style="display:none">|</span> <a style="display:none" href="#" currency="cad" id=""
        class="cad-btn currency-btn">CAN$</a>
    <span style="display:none">|</span> <a style="display:none" href="#" currency="mxn" id=""
        class="mxn-btn currency-btn">MEX$</a>
    <span style="display:none">|</span> <a style="display:none" href="#" currency="sgd" id=""
        class="sgd-btn currency-btn">SGP$</a>
    <span class='currency-more'>|</span>
    <a href="#" class="currency-more">Show more&hellip;</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fiddle :

https://jsfiddle.net/bshav9mj/1/

```
<div class="sec1">
  <div class="currency-btn-section">
    <h4>Section 1</h4>
    <b>CURRENCY:</b>
    <a href="#" data-currency="US" class="usd-btn currency-btn active">US$</a>
    <span>|</span> <a href="#" data-currency="GBP" class="gbp-btn currency-btn">GBP£</a>
    <span>|</span> <a href="#" data-currency="EUR" class="eur-btn currency-btn">EUR€</a>
    <span style="display:none">|</span> <a style="display:none" href="#" data-currency="AUS" class="aud-btn currency-btn">AUS$</a>
    <span style="display:none">|</span> <a style="display:none" href="#" data-currency="CAN" class="cad-btn currency-btn">CAN$</a>
    <span style="display:none">|</span> <a style="display:none" href="#" data-currency="MEX" class="mxn-btn currency-btn">MEX$</a>
    <span style="display:none">|</span> <a style="display:none" href="#" data-currency="SGP" class="sgd-btn currency-btn">SGP$</a>
    <span class='currency-more'>|</span>
    <a href="#" class="currency-more">Show more&hellip;</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="sec2">
  <h4>Section 2</h4>
  <b>CURRENCY:</b>
  <a href="#" data-currency="US" class="usd-btn currency-btn active">US$</a>
  <span>|</span> <a href="#" data-currency="GBP" class="gbp-btn currency-btn">GBP£</a>
  <span>|</span> <a href="#" data-currency="EUR" class="eur-btn currency-btn">EUR€</a>
  <span style="display:none">|</span> <a style="display:none" href="#" data-currency="AUS" class="aud-btn currency-btn">AUS$</a>
  <span style="display:none">|</span> <a style="display:none" href="#" data-currency="CAN" class="cad-btn currency-btn">CAN$</a>
  <span style="display:none">|</span> <a style="display:none" href="#" data-currency="MEX" class="mxn-btn currency-btn">MEX$</a>
  <span style="display:none">|</span> <a style="display:none" href="#" data-currency="SGP" class="sgd-btn currency-btn">SGP$</a>
  <span class='currency-more'>|</span>
  <a href="#" class="currency-more">Show more&hellip;</a>
</div>
<div class="sec3">
  <h4>Section 3</h4>
  <b>CURRENCY:</b>
  <a href="#" data-currency="US" class="usd-btn currency-btn active">US$</a>
  <span>|</span> <a href="#" data-currency="GBP" class="gbp-btn currency-btn">GBP£</a>
  <span>|</span> <a href="#" data-currency="EUR" class="eur-btn currency-btn">EUR€</a>
  <span style="display:none">|</span> <a style="display:none" href="#" data-currency="AUS" class="aud-btn currency-btn">AUS$</a>
  <span style="display:none">|</span> <a style="display:none" href="#" data-currency="CAN" class="cad-btn currency-btn">CAN$</a>
  <span style="display:none">|</span> <a style="display:none" href="#" data-currency="MEX" class="mxn-btn currency-btn">MEX$</a>
  <span style="display:none">|</span> <a style="display:none" href="#" data-currency="SGP" class="sgd-btn currency-btn">SGP$</a>
  <span class='currency-more'>|</span>
  <a href="#" class="currency-more">Show more&hellip;</a>
</div>
```

JS :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  var $ = jQuery;

  $('.currency-btn').on('click', function(event) {
    if (event) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
    var currency = $(this).data("currency");
    $('.currency-btn').removeClass('active');
    $('.currency-btn[data-currency="'+currency+'"]').addClass('active');
  });
  $('a.currency-more').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.currency-more').hide();
    $('.currency-btn').show();
    $('.sec1 span, .sec2 span, .sec3 span').show();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think much of your code is not necessary, and can be simplified. You also had some inconsistencies in your HTML, e.g. only `sec1` had a `<div class="currency-btn-section">` so I added it to the others.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var $ = jQuery;

    // Toggle hidden elements and the more buttons:
    $('a.currency-more').off('click').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('a.d-none, a.currency-more, span.d-none').toggle();
    });

    $('.currency-btn').off('click').on('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        // Deactivate all currencies:
        $('.currency-btn').removeClass('active');

        // Activate the current one:
        let cur = $(this)[0].classList[0];
        $('.' + cur).addClass('active')
    });
});
```

```css
.active { color: red; }
.d-none {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="sec1">
    <div class="currency-btn-section">
        <h4>Section 1</h4>
        <b>CURRENCY:</b>
        <a href="#" id="" class="usd-btn currency-btn active">US$</a>
        <span>|</span> <a href="#" id="" class="gbp-btn currency-btn">GBP£</a>
        <span>|</span> <a href="#" id="" class="eur-btn currency-btn">EUR€</a>
        <span class="d-none">|</span> <a class="d-none" href="#" id="" class="aud-btn currency-btn">AUS$</a>
        <span class="d-none">|</span> <a class="d-none" href="#" id="" class="cad-btn currency-btn">CAN$</a>
        <span class="d-none">|</span> <a class="d-none" href="#" id="" class="mxn-btn currency-btn">MEX$</a>
        <span class="d-none">|</span> <a class="d-none" href="#" id="" class="sgd-btn currency-btn">SGP$</a>
        <span class='currency-more'>|</span>
        <a href="#" class="currency-more">Show more&hellip;</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="sec2">
    <div class="currency-btn-section">
        <h4>Section 2</h4>
        <b>CURRENCY:</b>
        <a href="#" id="" class="usd-btn currency-btn active">US$</a>
        <span>|</span> <a href="#" id="" class="gbp-btn currency-btn">GBP£</a>
        <span>|</span> <a href="#" id="" class="eur-btn currency-btn">EUR€</a>
        <span class="d-none">|</span> <a class="d-none" href="#" id="" class="aud-btn currency-btn">AUS$</a>
        <span class="d-none">|</span> <a class="d-none" href="#" id="" class="cad-btn currency-btn">CAN$</a>
        <span class="d-none">|</span> <a class="d-none" href="#" id="" class="mxn-btn currency-btn">MEX$</a>
        <span class="d-none">|</span> <a class="d-none" href="#" id="" class="sgd-btn currency-btn">SGP$</a>
        <span class='currency-more'>|</span>
        <a href="#" class="currency-more">Show more&hellip;</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="sec3">
    <div class="currency-btn-section">
        <h4>Section 3</h4>
        <b>CURRENCY:</b>
        <a href="#" id="" class="usd-btn currency-btn active">US$</a>
        <span>|</span> <a href="#" id="" class="gbp-btn currency-btn">GBP£</a>
        <span>|</span> <a href="#" id="" class="eur-btn currency-btn">EUR€</a>
        <span class="d-none">|</span> <a class="d-none" href="#" id="" class="aud-btn currency-btn">AUS$</a>
        <span class="d-none">|</span> <a class="d-none" href="#" id="" class="cad-btn currency-btn">CAN$</a>
        <span class="d-none">|</span> <a class="d-none" href="#" id="" class="mxn-btn currency-btn">MEX$</a>
        <span class="d-none">|</span> <a class="d-none" href="#" id="" class="sgd-btn currency-btn">SGP$</a>
        <span class='currency-more'>|</span>
        <a href="#" class="currency-more">Show more&hellip;</a>
    </div>
</div>
```